# Black Screen after Adding MessageUI Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, sms, swrevealviewcontroller

I have an iPhone app that was working fine.  I wanted to add SMS and email functionality, but when I add the MessageUI Framework, after my launch screen loads instead of seeing my root Navigation Controller, the screen is black. Once I remove the framework, the app behaves as expected.

I've screenshotted the frameworks I'm using in the screenshot below. I'm not sure if there's some dependency that is tripping this up:

[image: libraries]

Additionally, I am using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController), and I have the following frameworks installed via cocoapods:

 
- AFNetworking 
- MBProgressHUD 
- SWTableViewCell

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:

I realized there was a try-catch statement in SWRevealViewController, and within the catch statement an exception was being triggered.  I've logged it here:

```
[29027:60b] NSException caught
2014-06-30 13:49:30.159 [29027:60b] Name: NSUnknownKeyException
2014-06-30 13:49:30.159 [29027:60b] Reason: [<MPViewController 0x10ce8f060> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key panGestureRecognizer.
```

I tried commenting out a line in MPViewController that referenced panGestureRecognizer, but still get same exception.

EDIT: changed UIMessage to MessageUI in subject and body

Comment: maybe you are linking an OSX framework an not an iOS one? Does the console display anything interesting?

Comment: Nope, nothing out of the ordinary is printed in the console. When I add the framework, I'm adding it from under the iOS7.1 folder so seems to be an iOS one